# SonarQube is ignoring all files in submodules: 11:55:09.209 DEBUG: File 'C:/...' is excluded by the scm ignore settings

Tags: sonarqube

I can't change any settings on the SonarQube server, I can only change the parameters I feed the scanner.

My 'sources' is actually pointing at a submodule's directory, but every file within it is ignored. It seems as though files in submodules are being ignored by SonarQube.

Is there any way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

try to disable the "sonar.scm.exclusions" setting, it works for us.

```
sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true
```